# Is $ f : \Bbb{R}^*\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^{pos}: f(x) = |x| $ a homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Pinter's A *Book of Abstract Algebra* problem B4 in chapter 14 asks me to prove that $ f : \Bbb{R}^*\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^{pos}: f(x) = |x| $ a homomorphism.  This means showing that $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) \;\forall x, y \in \Bbb{R}^*$.  But this doesn't seem to be true.  For $x = 4, y = -4, f(x + y) = | 4 + -4 | = 0$, but $f(x) + f(y) = |4| + |-4| = 8$.  So it's not a homomorphism.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation on $\mathbb{R}^*$ is multiplication, so you want to be showing that $f(x*y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$

Comment: How do you know that?  What is R*?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^*$ is the set of real numbers not including zero, this cannot be a group under addition because, for instance, $4+(-4)=0$ so it would not be closed under the operation. However, if the operation is taken to be multiplication, then one has, amongst the other axioms being satisfied, closure under multiplication; i.e. the product of two non-zero numbers is non-zero.